# This.href is always undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple gallery sing javascript (no jQuery). This is my html code

```
<section>
    <div class="gallery" align="center">
      <figure>
        <p id="imgTitle">Les frères Sherlockooooooo</p>
        <img src="../images/gallery/gal1.jpg" aligne="center" width="600" id="grande" 1px solid/>
      </figure>

      <article class="petite">
        <script>
                    for (var i=1; i<11 ; i++)
                    document.write('<a href="../images/gallery/gal'+i+'.jpg" onclick="return false;"> <img src="../images/gallery/thumbnails/gal' +i+ '_thumb.jpg" alt="gallery" class="thumbnails"></a>');
            </script>
      </article>
      <hr style="border-bottom: dotted 1px;"> </hr>
    </div>
  </section>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
window.onload=pageLoaded;

function pageLoaded() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails")[i].onclick=change_img;
  }
}

function change_img() {
  document.getElementById("grande").src=this.href;
  // beyond this part is experimental

  // end of experiment
}
```

What I want to make is to change the big image (the id is "grande") with another image by clicking the thumbnail. There is already a href inside the thumbnail, I expected a that the big image would change by changing the source of the big image with the href from the thumbnail, it turns out that only blank image showed up and it says that it's undefined. How to fix his? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing `.thumbnails` elements which are the `<img>` tag within your `<a>` tags.  Your `<a>` tag contains the href attribute and their *child*  tag contain a src attribute.

If you want the **href** tag, you'd need to assign the class of thumbnails to the `<a>` tag instead of the child or assign it it's own class name and reference that within your function.

```
<a href="../images/gallery/gal'+i+'.jpg" onclick="return false;">
  <img class="thumbnails"src="../images/gallery/thumbnails/gal' +i+ '_thumb.jpg" alt="gallery">
//       ^-- this tag doesn't contain a href attribute
</a>
```

Amending your `<a>` tags to this should fix your issue (without having to modify anything else in your code):

```
//       v-- class added here instead
<a class="thumbnails" href="../images/gallery/gal'+i+'.jpg" onclick="return false;">
  <img src="../images/gallery/thumbnails/gal' +i+ '_thumb.jpg" alt="gallery">
</a>
```